# Disable shortcuts alt + space browser

Tags: javascript

It's possible to disable the shortcuts <kbd>Alt + space</kbd> in firefox ?
I use the folowing code for other shortcuts

```
aEvent.altKey == xx
```

But with <kbd>Alt + space</kbd> it's different.

Comment: `if(event.altKey && event.key === ' ')`. A space for the space bar. Now space out on that.

Comment: The folowing code does not work :/

Comment: if(event.altKey && event.key === ' ')

Comment: if(event.altKey && event.key === 32)

Comment: if(event.altKey && event.key == ' ')

Comment: You don't really disable the keys. You just test for them, then do or don't execute code. Maybe you just want to `return false;`, but how should I know, you supplied so little code.

Comment: if (aEvent.altKey && (aEvent.keyCode == aEvent.DOM_VK_SPACE)){                      
         aEvent.preventDefault();
 return false;
}